# When the window is resized, everything is crunched instead of displaying a scrolling bar

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

So I'm developping MVC app and am not very experienced in this feature, and I have encountered a problem which bugs me.

My desktop resolution is 1920x1080. When any app is rolling in fullscreen, it displays normally. But if the window is resized (ex: clicking on the button on the upper-right border of the browser), everything gets crunched in the middle.

Or I would like at least that the full dimension width of my browser / app be maintained at all time and that a scrolling bar shows down on the page because I do not have the time / resources to work on a "resize" app or script, if that even exists.

Can anyone help me out? Don't hesitate to add information or ask for more info if you need, I love to learn new stuff.

**EDIT**

Here are some images took a short while ago. The normal view:

[image]

And when the window is resized:

[image]

Another image from another app:

[image]

And the same image when resized:

[image]

Like I said, in those 2 cases I would like everything to remain as they are and the user would have to scroll horizontally. I figure that it would be less "painful" to develop that way than to recalculate / resize everything...

**EDIT 2**

For those familiar with MVC templates, here's some coding that I have added for one of my app, maybe that will help me understand what's happening.

First the `_Layout` view:

```
<div id="body">
    <div>
        <div id="leftSide">
            @{
                Html.RenderAction("ShowCardSetLinks", "Home");
            }
        </div>
        <div id="inner">
            <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>  
        </div>
        <div id="rightSide">
            @{
                Html.RenderAction("GetCardOfTheDay", "Home");
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="dialog-modal" title="See Card Detail"></div>
</div>
```

Then the CSS I have added:

```
#body {
    width: 1920px;
    display: table-cell;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

#leftSide {
    width: 20%;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
}

#rightSide {
    width: 20%;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
}

#inner {
    width: 70%;
    display: table-cell;
    position: relative;
}
```

that's about it for the main layout, if I have anything else, I will post it.

Comment: can you post some print-screens or code snippet?

Comment: Print-screen, will try to do that.

Comment: What front-end framework, if any, are you using? Screenshot is going to do nothing for us to help. Give us code, preferably in a jsfiddle, or even a direct site link. Sounds more CSS (CSS Framework?) related to me...

Comment: @arturgrzesiak I have added images.

Comment: @MikeBarwick well except for what any MVC templates provides, I am not using any front-end framework. I do think too that it is css related, but I have no clue what's wrong and that's why I need help. As for code, I cannot provide some yet because, well, MVC templates do come with a huge bunch of CSS code...

Comment: I'm familiar with MVC - which by default does not come with default CSS, man. You or someone else added it. Looks like those side bars are positioned absolute or fixed and you have "Cards Advanced Search" section set as a fixed width...so when the browser shrinks, the section looks for somewhere to go. Use width percentages for the side bars (say 20% each), then 60% for the main content. make sure each is position:relative, float them to the left, and clear the float by adding clear:both to the parent div.

Comment: That's some interesting tips! I have already worked with floating divs, but not with relative positioning, will try that.

Comment: And, yes, I have added CSS styling, but I've tried at best not to touch the main css scripting.

Comment: @MikeBarwick I have added some coding up there, if you can make anything out of it, feel free to point!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `display: table-cell;` from all of your CSS. This is not proper structure. <strike>Especially remove it from the `body` tag and the table layout (awful bro). Why do you have a width on the body tag too - and for that large??</strike> This not good coding practice at all...change to this and let me know if it works. Wrap all your main content is a wrapper with the class I specified below.

You also had 70%, 20%, and 20% as widths. That's 110%. Obvs can't exceed 100%. I changed this.

**EDIT:** I see that you had an ID named BODY and it wasn't the `body` tag (you should rename this). My mistake. See update below...

```
#body {
position:relative;
margin:0 auto;
width:100%; // change it to whatever value you want your site, but don't exceed 980px. Just leave it at 100% if you want a fluid site.
overflow: hidden;
clear:both;
}

#leftSide {
width: 20%;
position: relative;
float:left;
}

#rightSide {
width: 20%;
position: relative;
float:left;
}

#inner {
width: 60%;
position: relative;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: To answer: I used `display: table-cell;` because I wanted to have sidebars without using `float`. But I have yet to try it this way. I will try what you are suggesting, though, because as you mentioned it, I want to learn proper coding practice in HTML :)

Comment: As a general rule of thumb - stay away from tables unless your using table HTML to code your site or you want to make a data table of some sorts. Don't convert DIVs to tables...uggggglllly. You'll just run into problems.

Comment: Thanks. I've been avoiding table unless, as you mension, I have to display data tables.